# Deletar imagem do BD e da Pasta

Tags: php, pdo, arquivo

Estou tentando criar um *script* que exclua a imagem do banco de daos e da pasta, mas o problema é que só está excluindo do BD e não da pasta.

```
Tabela equipes
id, nome, foto
```

Aqui é o PHP que estou usando:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["deletar"])){
        $sqlDeletar = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM equipes WHERE id = :id");
        $sqlDeletar->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $sqlDeletar->execute();
        $dadosDeletar = $sqlDeletar->fetchObject();
        unlink("../upload/".$dadosDeletar->foto);
        echo "Aqui é o link de redirecionar.";
    }else{
        if(isset($_POST["nao"])){
            echo "Aqui é o link de redirecionar.";
        }
    }
}
```

E aqui o formulário:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="deletar" value="Excluir">
        <input type="submit" name="nao" value="Não excluir">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Você precisa fazer um select antes de deletar um registro. Pois, depois que é excluído você não tem mais a opção "$dados->foto"

Answer (score -1):

Faça uma verificação pra saber se o arquivo existe.

```
if (is_file("../upload/".$dadosDeletar->foto)) {/*excluir imagem*/}
```

Certifique-se de que `$dadosDeletar->foto` retorna o valor esperado e que você está passando o caminho correto para a pasta upload.

Comment: ta dando o msm error, será que não está habilitado alguma coisa no php.ini ?

Comment: Por favor, informe o erro na sua pergunta.

Comment: Ta dando esse error: General error in

Answer (score -1):

Como o amigo disse ali nos comentários você precisa fazer um select na foto antes de remover do banco, mais ou menos assim.

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["deletar"])){
        
        /* Primeiro você precisa saber o nome do arquivo */
        /* Selecione o mesmo no banco */
        $sqlSelect = $pdo->prepare("SELECT foto FROM equipes WHERE id = :id");
        $sqlSelect->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $sqlSelect->execute();
        $dadosSelect = $sqlSelect->fetchObject();

        /* É legal você verificar se o arquivo está lá na pasta */
        if (is_file("../upload/".$dadosSelect->foto)) {
            /* Remove o arquivo */
            unlink("../upload/".$dadosSelect->foto);
        }

        /* Aqui deleta o banco */
        $sqlDeletar = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM equipes WHERE id = :id");
        $sqlDeletar->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $sqlDeletar->execute();

        echo "Aqui é o link de redirecionar.";

    }else{

        if(isset($_POST["nao"])){
            echo "Aqui é o link de redirecionar.";
        }

    }
}
```

Meu forte não é PDO, mas acho que é essa a solução que precisa.

Answer (score -2):

if(isset($_GET['delete'])){

```
$id_e = $_GET['delete'];
$sql = "select * from empresa where id_e = ".$id_e;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $userPic = $row['logo'];
  unlink($upload_dir.$userPic);
  $sql = "delete from empresa where id_e=".$id_e;
  if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    header('location:produtos.php');
  }
}
```

}

( essa e a parte da imagem(logo) com o (id) na tabela empresa ... entendeu ,,vc precisa colocar a imagem e o id juntos ao deletar

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).